# Swift: Sort Dictionary of Number Strings

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a Dictionary of number String that looks like this:

```
let comph : [String : [String : String]] = [
             "1":["title" : "first title"], 
             "2":["title" : "second title"],
             "10": ["title" : "last title"]
             ]
```

Then when I sort my Dictionary using `comph.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }` I get this:

```
let sortedComph = comph.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }
print(sortedComph) //["1":["title" : "first title"],"10": ["title" : "last title"],"2":["title" : "second title"]]
```

How can I sort the Dictionary so that it returns the keys in numerical order?

eg: `["1":["title" : "first title"],"2":["title" : "second title"],"10": ["title" : "last title"]]`

Thanks'

Comment: Yeah, I understand that thought I would check if there was a way to order what I have already. I most likely will end up using an multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries in Swift, by definition, are unsorted collections. You'll need to use some other type if you want to maintain order.

But, it looks like this guy wrote an `OrderedDictionary` in Swift, if you're interested:

[Learning Swift: Ordered Dictionaries](http://timekl.com/blog/2014/06/02/learning-swift-ordered-dictionaries/)

Or, a quick n' dirty solution would be to extract the keys to an array, sort those, then iterate over the array and do a dictionary lookup using the keys.

Comment: Yeah I do think it would just be best to move over to an array

Answer (score 1):

The `sortedComph` constant in your example is no longer a dictionary, but an array of (key, value) tuples. The problem you're running into is that when sorting strings, the comparison is done without treating the strings as numeric values. *That's* what you need to fix.

One way to handle this is by creating `Int?` instances from your strings in your comparison function:

```
let sortedComph = comph.sort { Int($0.0) < Int($1.0) }
// [("1", ["title": "first title"]), ("2", ["title": "second title"]), ("10", ["title": "last title"])]
```

That way the resulting array will be sorted by the integer value of what's in the string keys. Any non-Integer keys will be grouped at the beginning of the list, since that's how `nil` sorts.

The more robust way is probably to use the `NSString.compare(:options:)` method:

```
let sortedComph = comph.sort {
    ($0.0 as NSString).compare($1.0, options: .NumericSearch) == .OrderedAscending
}
// [("1", ["title": "first title"]), ("2", ["title": "second title"]), ("10", ["title": "last title"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want you could have an array of structure representing your data

```
struct Model
{
  var key:String!
  var title:String!
  // etc...
}
```

Then declare the array of that structure:

```
     var arrayOfStructure = [Model]()
```

Then you sorted it

Comment: While that will have an order, it won't be sorted. To do the sorting, you'll want to also have Model conform to Comparable and then do a sort on the arrayOfStructure.